# How do I stop keystrokes being repeated when using x2go?

Tags: x2go

When connecting to my desktop via x2go, I am getting major key repeating. Even if I tap the key as quickly as I can, sometimes it's just as if it was held for as long as it take the UI to update. I use this same keyboard on the desktop I'm remoting into and it works fine, so I know that is not the problem.